# Why doens't the form use my method from my Controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This form instead using the "Verify function in my controllers goes to the subpage /Account/Verify
Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Verify", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <span>Enter Your Email:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)<br />
    <span>Enter Your Password:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Password)<br />
    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Method:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Verify(Account acc)
{
    connectionString();
    con.Open();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = "select * from Users where Name = '"+acc.Name+"' and password = '"+acc.Password+"'";
    dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        con.Close();
        return View("Home");
    }
    else {
        con.Close();
        return View("Privacy");     
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding picture so the Controller and it's location are visible

[image]

I feel like I tried everything rn and I'm out of ideas how could I do this

I wanted the form proceed and to be redirected to one of the subpages I've Pointed

Comment: You have mentioned `"Account"` controller, so it will always find `Account` controller and then find Action Method `"Verify"`. What do you mean by `subpage /Account/Verify`

Comment: @harrysrangal I've added an ss to the Post, are you maybe able to show me how it should be written?

Comment: "Verify" Method is inside Account Controller, right? Can you show which method is getting hit and which method is expected to be hit?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to mark your HttpMethod in controller.
Like:

```
[HttpPost("Verify")] 
public ActionResult Verify(Account acc)
```

Also in the browser please open developer tools windows (F12 or Right click and inspect will enough for it.) after then go to network tab. You can see the network requests on there. Just keep monitoring the network packages and press the form submit button then verify is your endpoint correct or not.

Answer (score -1):

it finally worked, this is how it should be:

`Html.BeginForm("Verify", "Account", FormMethod.Post`

So basically first goes method name and second in controller name, but I'm sure I've tried this couple of times, but it didn't work previously.
Anyway the problem seems solved for now

Comment: Seems like your code suddenly started working in some mystical way. But actually the reason is your browser cache, which was cleared after some time interval

Comment: Yeah, it might be it. I will keep this in mind so I will avoid posting such lame posts